# yii2 config\db.php secure?

Tags: security, yii2

I'm using the framework [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html) for the first time and I was wondering if it is secure to write in plain text my database's password in config\db.php? Or is their a more secure way to access to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be secure enough as long you are not exposing this file to public users.

You can store it anywhere on the server basically (as long as it's not exposed to public users) but application should be able to get it fast and easy (to not provide additional delay for the database connection).

Comment: I accepted as an answer because it's true in any case but the answer of @S Rana and @karpy47 are correct too.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Git, I believe it is a bad idea to commit any file with a password in it. Personally I keep a separate file with a few crucial passwords outside of Git and load that file in to get the values, like this...

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('path/passwords.ini', true);

return [
    'class'    => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn'      => $config['db']['dsn'],
    'username' => $config['db']['username'],
    'password' => $config['db']['password'],
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
];
```

Where passwords.ini would look like...

```
// My password file
[db]
dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx"
username="xxx"
password="xxx"
```

You could leave db.php out of Git, but I find this more convenient, especially for other config-files where many settings does not affect security.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you created an extra file. In your `common\config` folder,you will get `main-local.php`. You can define your Connection credentials in there.

By default that file will be ignored by git.

Comment: You are right, but I also like to use the environment settings (Yii2 adv template), that overwrite common/config/main-local.php. Guess you could argue that I should leave environments/dev/common/config/main-local.php  out of Git also. But then I miss some other settings that I would like to keep in Git. Yii2 simply does not have a built in separation of password-settings and other-settings.
In the end I believe it boils down to personal preferences also. It works either way, you just need to stick to something. For me, having a separate file with passwords seemed like a better practice.

Comment: Yii2 have file separation `main-local.php`,`main.php`, `params-local.php` and `params.php` . Local files ment to be kept away from git , others things which is need to keep in git mentaion in other files.